# Passing arabic parameters to oracle stored procedure

Tags: java, oracle, arabic

I'm trying to pass arabic input as parameters to Oracle stored procedure from Java

to make search on it.

but there is no results, but if i called the procedure in SQL Developer

there is no problem

can any body help me ?

Comment: Consider posting some *actual* example code. How is the stored procedure being called? Are placeholders used? Etc.

Comment: It doesn't look like your input is being passed with the correct charset/encoding to the stored procedure. You might want to post code to aid in debugging, especially where you are setting the encoding in Java, and how you are calling the stored procedure. Additionally, it would also be good to provide the locale of the OS that the client is running on, or the locale set by the code.

Comment: Make sure the character set is specified correctly. Try a round-trip `SELECT ? from dual` and see if you get the correct string back.

Comment: thanks every body, it is resolved